# IIS Rewrite Rule pattern issue (1 matches 10, 2 matches 20, etc)

Tags: design-patterns, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to write a handful of IIS rewrite URLs, but I have an issue with my pattern format.  It seems the pattern is too vague and 1 is matching 10, 11, 12 (anything that starts with 1) and 2 is matching 20, 21, 22 (anything that starts with 2).

Here is a sample rule

```
<rule name="=Metrics ID 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="metrics/index\.cfm$" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="site_id=1" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://domain.com/testing123" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

This rule fires when site_id=1, but it also fires when site_id=10.

How can I change the pattern so that it only fires on site_id=1?  And site_id=2 doesn't fire on 20, 21, etc.

Answer (score 0):

pattern="site_id=\b1\b" worked.